# Spring boot Multiple routes with multiple JWT using different Entities table and Repositories

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I need to manage multiple JWT authentication systems in my application, perhaps invoking different filters based on what the request url contains (e.g. /admin, /operator. Must use separate @Entity and @Repository) . Here is my code:

```
        @Configuration
        @RequiredArgsConstructor
        public class ApplicationConfig {
        
            @Qualifier("rpst-operatore-generico-backoffice")
            private final OperatoreRepository operatoreRepository;
            @Qualifier("rpst-utente-condiviso-template1")
            private final UtenteRepository utenteRepository;
        
            
            @Bean
            @Primary
            public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceGenerico() {
                return username -> operatoreRepository.findById(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Operatore non trovato."));
            }
        
            @Bean
            public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceTemplate1() {
                return username -> utenteRepository.findById(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Utente non trovato."));
            }
        
            @Bean
            @Primary
            public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderGenerico() {
              DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
              authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceGenerico());
              authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
              return authProvider;
            }
        
            @Bean
            public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderTemplate1() {
              DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
              authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceTemplate1());
              authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
              return authProvider;
            }
          
            @Bean
            public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
              return config.getAuthenticationManager();
            }
          
            @Bean
            public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
              return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            }
        
        }
    
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @EnableMethodSecurity
    public class SecurityConfigGenerico {
    
            private final FiltroAutenticazioneJwt filtroAutenticazioneJwt;
            private final AuthenticationProvider providerAutenticazione;
    
            @Bean
            SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                    return http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
                        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
                        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
                        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                        return configuration;
                    }))
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(
                            authorize ->{
                                    try {
                                            authorize.antMatchers(WhiteListURL.WHITE_LIST).permitAll()
                                            .antMatchers("/api/v1/autenticazione/registrazione").hasRole(SUPERADMIN.name())
                                            .antMatchers("/api/v1/autenticazione/disconnessione").hasAnyRole(SUPERADMIN.name(), AMMINISTRATORE.name(), OPERATORE.name(), OSPITE.name())                                            
                                            .and()
                                            .authenticationProvider(providerAutenticazione)
                                            .addFilterBefore(filtroAutenticazioneJwt, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
                                            //.logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/autenticazione/disconnessione")
                                            //.addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                                            //.logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()));
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
                    )
                    .build();
            }
    
            /*
             * @Bean
             * JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
             * var jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
             * jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
             * jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("groups");
             * 
             * var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
             * jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(
             * jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
             * return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
             * }
             */
    
    }
    
    
    @Service
    public class ServizioJwt {
        
        @Value("${application.security.jwt.secret-key}")
        private String secretKey;
        @Value("${application.security.jwt.expiration}")
        private long jwtExpiration;
        @Value("${application.security.jwt.refresh-token.expiration}")
        private long refreshExpiration;
      
        public String estraiUsername(String token) {
          return estraiClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
        }
      
        public <T> T estraiClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
          final Claims claims = estraiTutteLeClaims(token);
          return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
        }
      
        public String generaToken(UserDetails dettaglioUtente) {
          return generaToken(new HashMap<>(), dettaglioUtente);
        }
      
        public String generaToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails dettaglioUtente
        ) {
          return costruisciToken(extraClaims, dettaglioUtente, jwtExpiration);
        }
      
        public String generaRefreshToken(
            UserDetails dettaglioUtente
        ) {
          return costruisciToken(new HashMap<>(), dettaglioUtente, refreshExpiration);
        }
      
        private String costruisciToken(
                Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
                UserDetails dettaglioUtente,
                long expiration
        ) {
          return Jwts
                  .builder()
                  .setClaims(extraClaims)
                  .setSubject(dettaglioUtente.getUsername())
                  .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                  .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiration))
                  .signWith(ottieniSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                  .compact();
        }
      
        public boolean flagValiditaToken(String token, UserDetails dettaglioUtente) {
          final String username = estraiUsername(token);
          return (username.equals(dettaglioUtente.getUsername())) && !flagScadenzaToken(token);
        }
      
        private boolean flagScadenzaToken(String token) {
          return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
        }
      
        private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
          return estraiClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
        }
      
        private Claims estraiTutteLeClaims(String token) {
          return Jwts
              .parserBuilder()
              .setSigningKey(ottieniSignInKey())
              .build()
              .parseClaimsJws(token)
              .getBody();
        }
      
        private Key ottieniSignInKey() {
          byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secretKey);
          return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
        }
    
        public static final String estraiTokenDaHeader(String authHeader) {
          return authHeader.substring(7);
      }
    }
    
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class FiltroAutenticazioneJwt extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
      private final ServizioJwt servizioJwt;
      private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
      private final TokenOperatoreRepository tokenRepository;
    
      @Override
      protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
          @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String codiceFiscale;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
          ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Token non valido.");
          return;
        }
        try {
          if (request.getRequestURI().contains("refresh-token")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
          } else {
            jwt = ServizioJwt.estraiTokenDaHeader(authHeader);
            codiceFiscale = servizioJwt.estraiUsername(jwt);
            if (codiceFiscale != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
              UserDetails dettaglioUtente = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(codiceFiscale);
              boolean flagValiditaToken = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
                  .map(t -> !t.isScaduto() && !t.isRevocato())
                  .orElse(false);
              if (servizioJwt.flagValiditaToken(jwt, dettaglioUtente) && flagValiditaToken) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    dettaglioUtente,
                    null,
                    dettaglioUtente.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(
                    new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
              }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
          }
    
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
          if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/disconnessione")) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                "Anomalia logout. Token assente.");
          } else {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Token scaduto.");
          }
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
          ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, "Errore token.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    
      @Override
      protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        return Arrays.stream(WhiteListURL.WHITE_LIST)
            .anyMatch(e -> new AntPathMatcher().match(e, request.getServletPath()));
      }
    
    }


@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "operatore", schema = "public")
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Operatore implements Serializable, UserDetails {
    
    //ATTRIBUTI
    @Id
    @Column(name = "codice_fiscale", nullable = false, unique=true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Non è possibile inserire un Codice fiscale vuoto.")
    private String codiceFiscale;

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Non è possibile inserire un Nome vuoto.")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "cognome", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Non è possibile inserire un Cognome vuoto.")
    private String cognome;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    @Email(message = "Indirizzo Email non valido.")
    @NotBlank(message = "Non è possibile inserire una Email vuota.")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "data_creazione", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime dataCreazione;

    @Column(name = "data_aggiornamento")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime dataAggiornamento;

    @Column(name = "abilitazione_email", columnDefinition = "boolean default false", nullable = false)
    private Boolean abilitazioneEmail;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password; 
    
    @Column(name = "tipologia", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255) default 'OSPITE'", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TipologiaBackoffice tipologia;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operatore")
    private List<TokenOperatore> tokens;

    //RELAZIONI
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operatore", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Associazione> listaAssociazioni;

    public Operatore(String codiceFiscale, String nome, String cognome, String email) {
        this.codiceFiscale = codiceFiscale;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Operatore(String codiceFiscale, String nome, String cognome, String email, Boolean abilitazioneEmail, TipologiaBackoffice tipologia) {
        this.codiceFiscale = codiceFiscale;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.email = email;
        this.abilitazioneEmail = abilitazioneEmail;
        this.tipologia = tipologia;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void trasformazioneAttributiPrimoSalvataggio() {
        if(this.codiceFiscale != null) {
            this.codiceFiscale = this.codiceFiscale.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.nome != null) {
            this.nome = this.nome.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.cognome != null) {
            this.cognome = this.cognome.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.email != null) {
            this.email = this.email.toLowerCase();
        }
        if(this.abilitazioneEmail == null) {
            this.abilitazioneEmail = false;
        }
        if(this.tipologia == null) {
            this.tipologia = TipologiaBackoffice.OSPITE;
        }
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void trasformazioneAttributiAggiornamento() {
        if(this.codiceFiscale != null) {
            this.codiceFiscale = this.codiceFiscale.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.nome != null) {
            this.nome = this.nome.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.cognome != null) {
            this.cognome = this.cognome.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.email != null) {
            this.email = this.email.toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return tipologia.ottieniTipologia();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return codiceFiscale;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}


@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "utente", schema = "template1")
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Utente implements Serializable, UserDetails {
    
     //ATTRIBUTI
     @Id
     @Column(name = "identificativo", nullable = false, unique=true)
     @NotBlank(message = "Non è possibile inserire un identificativo vuoto.")
     private String identificativo;

     @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Non è possibile inserire un nome vuoto.")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "cognome", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Non è possibile inserire un cognome vuoto.")
    private String cognome;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    @Email(message = "Indirizzo email non valido.")
    @NotBlank(message = "Non è possibile inserire una email vuota.")
    private String email;

    //@Column(name = "token")
    //private String token;

    @Column(name = "tipo")
    private String tipo;

    @Column(name = "data_creazione", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime dataRegistrazione;

    @Column(name = "data_aggiornamento")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime dataAggiornamento;

    @Column(name = "data_abilitazione")
    private LocalDateTime dataAbilitazione;

    @Column(name = "data_disabilitazione")
    private LocalDateTime dataDisabilitazione;

    @Column(name = "abilitato", columnDefinition = "boolean default false", nullable = false)
    private Boolean abilitato;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password; 

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utente")
    private List<TokenUtente> tokens;

    //RELAZIONI
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<IstanzaTmp1> listaIstanze;


    public Utente(String identificativo, String nome, String cognome, String email, String tipo) {
        this.identificativo = identificativo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.email = email;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void trasformazioneAttributiPrimoSalvataggio() {
        if(this.identificativo != null) {
            this.identificativo = this.identificativo.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.nome != null) {
            this.nome = this.nome.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.cognome != null) {
            this.cognome = this.cognome.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.email != null) {
            this.email = this.email.toLowerCase();
        }
        if(this.abilitato == null) {
            this.abilitato = true;
        }
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void trasformazioneAttributiAggiornamento() {
        if(this.identificativo != null) {
            this.identificativo = this.identificativo.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.nome != null) {
            this.nome = this.nome.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.cognome != null) {
            this.cognome = this.cognome.toUpperCase();
        }
        if(this.email != null) {
            this.email = this.email.toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return identificativo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

The following code is currently not re-adapted as I am already getting StackOverflowError issues after adding:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceGenerico() {
    return username -> operatoreRepository.findById(username)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Operatore non trovato."));
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceTemplate1() {
    return username -> utenteRepository.findById(username)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Utente non trovato."));
}

@Bean
@Primary
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderGenerico() {
  DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
  authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceGenerico());
  authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProviderTemplate1() {
  DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
  authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceTemplate1());
  authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  return authProvider;
}
```

to manage multiple providers. I would like to understand what I am doing wrong and if I am handling it right being new to spring security. Thank you.